# Effects of z-index on drag and drop between two divs

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, z-index

I have two container divs and want to drag and drop elements between them.  I can drag and drop elements from the second container to the first but not the other way around.  The problem is that the elements of the first container seem to have a lower z-index than the second container.  When I drag them they slide under the second container.  What must I do to have all the the elements be on top and be draggable to any droppable container?  This is the fiddle showing the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/vfAgd/12/

If you drag an element from container 1 to container 2, it goes under container 2.  If you drag an element from container 2 you are able to drag it over container 1.  This happens because container 2 is added to the document after container 1.

Comment: There is no z-index issue with your fiddle in eitehr chrome, firefox 6 or ie9 - what browser is giving you trouble?

Comment: @MartinJespersen this happens on ie9.

Comment: well in ie9 on my machine it works just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this I had to remove the z-index for the containers.

```
.comdiv  { 
   padding: 0;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-left: 20px;
   border: 1px solid DarkKhaki;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px DarkKhaki;
   /* z-index: 26; */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vfAgd/17/ .

Answer (score 0):

There is a class name that jQuery UI [draggable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#theming) add to elements that are dragging. This class is removed after drag finishes. This class called `ui-draggable-dragging`. if you add an high z-index to the `ui-draggable-dragging` class your problem will be solved.
It should solve your problem. It seems your code have bugs. Debug it and add this css. It will work then.

```
 .ui-draggable-dragging{z-index:9999;}
```

Comment: Setting the z-index in the CSS styles for the UI draggable did not fix the problem.